# In MySql 5, can i add a trigger to a table without locking it?

Tags: mysql, triggers, locking

I have a large table that I'd prefer to leave unlocked when I add new trigger.
Is this technically possible, or just unwise?

Current approach:

```sql
    LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE

    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_trigger

    CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      ...
    END

    UNLOCK TABLES
```

Comment: Locking not needed during creation/dropping the trigger.

Comment: @Akina could you tell me why, or give a reference to documentation?

Comment: Reference manual tells nothing about locking needed during trigger creation. If locking was needed RM should tell about this.